# HTACCESS / ErrorDocument - How to serve 410 instead of 403

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-410

Can anyone please tell me how to server 410 instead of 403 (without serving any html page in 403)?

Like instead of:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

we need something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403:410 #/i.e. 403 will show default browser's 410/Gone error
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still didn't find any solution try this one
file: .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

And in 403.php use following code:

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.0 410 Gone"); ?>
```